# Angular2 Error - Is platform module (BrowserModule) included?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I'm just trying to run a simple index.html page in **Angular2**, but its showing me an error in zone.js in console:

```
    Unhandled Promise rejection: No ErrorHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule) included? ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: No ErrorHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule) included?
    at eval (application_ref.ts:364)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.ts:296)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:141)
    at NgZone.run (ng_zone.ts:153)
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone (application_ref.ts:359)
    at eval (application_ref.ts:330)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:141) Error: No ErrorHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule) included?
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4531:23)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3922:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:390:32)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:141:43)
    at NgZone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3853:69)
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleFactoryWithZone (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4526:23)
    at eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4568:59)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:26)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:141:43)
```

Can someone help me basically what it is and how to fix this. Module File:

```
import {Component, NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {App} from "./app";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [App],
    bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Comment: post your code for app module.

Comment: the error message is pretty clear

Answer (score 15):

You are missing the

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Add to your app module

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
]
...})
```