# ionic serve gives error in Chrome: Illegal constructor in CreateClass in core.js

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have recently taken over an Ionic project and working on getting it to work. The project runs on device, but I'm trying to get it to work in browser as well.

I have updated to the newest versions for plugins and dependencies, but now I'm stuck on a strange javascript error in Chrome console. After this error appeared, the app on device is also just white after the spalsh screen. I guess this is the same javascript error.

First I got this:
[image]

Then, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45256883/3301138), I got rid of the error, but got a new one which I cant for the life of me figure out of. Cant find anyone having the same issue either.

This is what I see in the console when running 'ionic serve':

[image: Errors in Chrome console]

Please help if you know what can cause this! How can I get rid of this error and get the app to run?

EDIT: I think maybe it can have something to do with the app.module code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { LongPress } from '../components/long-press/long-press';
import { MyApp } from './app.components';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { AddSkypeUserPage } from '../pages/add-skype-user/add-skype-user';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { DagsVisningPage } from '../pages/dags-visning/dags-visning';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { InnstillingerPage } from '../pages/innstillinger/innstillinger';
import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';
import { NyAktivitetPage } from '../pages/ny-aktivitet/ny-aktivitet';
import { CameraPopoverPage } from '../pages/ny-aktivitet/camera-popover';
import { ScoreboardPage } from '../pages/scoreboard/scoreboard';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';
import { UkesplanleggerPage } from '../pages/ukesplanlegger/ukesplanlegger';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LongPress,
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    AddSkypeUserPage,
    ContactPage,
    DagsVisningPage,
    HomePage,
    InnstillingerPage,
    LoginPage,
    NyAktivitetPage,
    CameraPopoverPage,
    ScoreboardPage,
    TabsPage,
    UkesplanleggerPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    AddSkypeUserPage,
    ContactPage,
    DagsVisningPage,
    HomePage,
    InnstillingerPage,
    LoginPage,
    NyAktivitetPage,
    CameraPopoverPage,
    ScoreboardPage,
    TabsPage,
    UkesplanleggerPage
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have cleared out the app module and the app components code and got the same error. I also tried starting a new project and copying in bits of the code to try to eliminate the problem, but was not able to find the issue, got the same errors in the new project. Seems like there are some errors connected to versions of specific dependencies or something. I have no idea...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally found the stupid problem by removing bits of code part by part!

It was due to the change of Storage to IonicStorageModule.

If you experience the same, you should add:

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from "@ionic/storage";
```

and:

```
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    BrowserModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
```

to your app.module.ts, but keep using:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
```

in your other classes.

Comment: Don't you need to add Storage to your app's providers in app.module.ts? My situation is the same as the one you suggest but I'm still experiencing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

did you try ionic lab? [here](https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-lab/) is the documentation.it much easier to test your apps on multiple screen sizes and platform types

```
ionic serve --lab
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to inject a StorageService in a class ,and I found after researching about this error , I would have to put `import  {Storage} from '@ionic/storage-angular';` in StorageService.js even i put `private myStorage: Storage` in the constructor of StorageService

it could be the same pattern
Cordially